# Why does my method keep returning 0

Tags: java, android, return, return-value

I have some code here where I have a getItem() method where it won't return anything else but zero . I am wondering why I am trying to move forward but can't without this in the way . Can anyone help ? Every time I compare the getItem() with a zero or  1 it always appears zero no matter what here is the code I can post more of my code such as other files if needed but this should be enough for now . please help ????

```
    package com.mycompany.myapp;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.lang.reflect.*;

    public class ActivityProducer
    {
        public HashMap<Class<?>, Integer> recipe = new HashMap<Class<?>, Integer>();

        public ActivityProducer(){
        }

         public int getItem(){
             int index = 0;
             for(Class<?> i : recipe.keySet()){
                 index = recipe.get(i);
             }
             return index;
         }

         public Class<?> getName(){
             Class<?> name = null;
             for(Class<?> names : recipe.keySet()){
                 name = names;
             }
             return name;
         }

         public Class<?>[] getNames(){
             Class<?>[] names = new Class<?>[recipe.size()];
              List<Class<?>> n = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

             n.addAll(recipe.keySet());

              for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
                 names[i] = n.get(i);
             }
             return names;
         }
     }
```

The recipe is a hashmap where it takes a Class type for the key and a Integer type for the value . every time I compare the getItem() with a number zero always wins why ????? All of the other methods are working just not that one ????? There has to be a reason why this is happening

Here is the main activity code

```
    package com.mycompany.myapp;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.os.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.content.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        private Intent intent;
        private ActivityProducer producer;
        private Extendible ex;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            producer = new ActivityProducer();

    producer.recipe.put(ChileConLecheActivity.class, 1);
    producer.recipe.put(ArrozActivity.class, 2);
    producer.recipe.put(EnchiladasActivity.class, 3);
    producer.recipe.put(SopaActivity.class, 4);

    ex = new Extendible();

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mainGridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent , View view , int position , long id ){
            for(int i = 0; i < producer.recipe.keySet().size(); i++){
                if(position == i){
                    //make content view for each recipe

                            startActivity(makeIntent(position, producer.recipe));


                }
            }
        }
    });




}

private Intent makeIntent(int recipe , HashMap<Class<?>, Integer> map){
    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
        for(Class<?> m : map.keySet()){
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , m);
        }
    }
    return intent;
}
    }
```

And here is the code where I am trying to switch layouts or where the call is

```
        package com.mycompany.myapp;
        import android.app.*;
        import android.os.*;
        import android.widget.*;
        import android.text.*;
        import android.content.*;

        public class Extendible extends Activity implements IActivities
    {
private LinearLayout layout;
private ActivityProducer pro;

public Extendible(){
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipes_layout);

    pro = new ActivityProducer();

    if(pro.getItem() == 1){
        chileConLecheLayout();
    } else if(pro.getItem() == 2){
        arrozLayout();
    }
}

public void chileConLecheLayout(){
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recipes_layoutLinearLayout);
    TextView recipeName = new TextView(Extendible.this);
    recipeName.setText("Chile Con Leche");
    recipeName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    recipeName.setTextSize(60);
    layout.addView(recipeName);
}

public void arrozLayout(){
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recipes_layoutLinearLayout);
    TextView recipeName = new TextView(Extendible.this);
    recipeName.setText("Arroz");
    recipeName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    recipeName.setTextSize(60);
    layout.addView(recipeName);
}

public void enchiladasLayout(){
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recipes_layoutLinearLayout);
    TextView recipeName = new TextView(Extendible.this);
    recipeName.setText("Enchiladas");
    recipeName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    recipeName.setTextSize(60);
    layout.addView(recipeName);
}
    }
```

Comment: Where do put values in your recipe map?

Comment: It looks like recipe.put(enchiladas.class, 0); and recipe.put(tacos.class, 1); and so on in the main activity class

Comment: Should I post more code ???

Comment: Yes, please post the call, too.

Comment: Okay one moment

Comment: Okay I have posted more code ??? What do u think is wrong with the getItem() method it doesn't work at all ? All the others work but this one . I have no idea why ??? Its very important one as u can see please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You use the Map in a strange way; your getItem() will just iterate over the keySet and return the last entry (note that Sets are not ordered, so this is basically random).

The way I understand your code, you would like to get index associated with a class, which would look like this:

```
public int getItem(Class clazz) {
    int index = 0;
    if(recipe.get(clazz) != null) {
        index = recipe.get(clazz);
    }

    return index;
}
```